# DI with cyclic dependency with custom HTTP and ConfigService

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a ConfigService to retrieve the right configuration for the right environment in the project. I'm currently encountering a cyclic dependancy

```
(index):28 Error: (SystemJS) Provider parse errors:
    Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Http: in NgModule AppModule
    Error: Provider parse errors:
```

I've explored the code and there is the problem, in my opinion:

CustomHttp

```
constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, public spinnerService: SpinnerService, public exceptionService: ExceptionService, public configService: ConfigService)
```

ExceptionService

```
constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService, private _spinnerService: SpinnerService, private _configService: ConfigService, private _router: Router)
```

ConfigService

```
constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

As you can see, I've a cyclic dependancies illustrated in this diagram (without any good convention):

[image]

My question now is, how to fix it? I've heard of `Injector` but I'm not sure I can really use it in this context.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

DI can't resolve cyclic dependencies. A workaround is to inject the injector and acquire the instance imperatively:

```ts
@Injectable()
class ConfigService {
  private http: Http;
  constructor(injector:Injector) {
    setTimeout(() => this.http = injector.get(Http);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there in the meantime another approach with Angular 4?

Comment: That is for Angular 2 - 4

Comment: I hoped in the meantime there is an improvement for this.

Comment: There are no plans to change that. This would required to change how constructors work in TypeScript in a way nobody would want them  to be changes. Don't expect a change here.

Comment: I just tested without,  and then with the setTimeout. And it works only with the latter. Any hint of why the delay is required?

Comment: Because `new ConfigService()` needs to return, and only afterwards can `injector.get(Http)` create a `Http` instance that depends on `ConfigService`.
*In the midst* of the constructor of `ConfigService` it's not possible for `injector.get(Http)` get an instance. `setTimeout()` allows to complete the constructor, and only later requests the `Http` class. This `setTimeout` is what actually breaks the cycle, the other stuff is just boilerplate for that.

Comment: There is now a more direct support for this kind of dependency: [ForwardRef](https://angular.io/api/core/forwardRef).

Comment: `forwardRef` doesn't help for that. `forwardRef` is only for static analysis of TS code, not for breaking up circular dependencies in DI.