# Is there a way in Angular 2 to pass data betwen services?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I need to pass data from Service1 to Service2

**Service1**

```
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
    ...
}
```

similar for Service2

the only way I found to make Service1 communicate with Service 2 is using window['var'] (set in Service1, read in Service2)

I think this is more a "hack" than a real solution but injecting a 3rd service doesn't work.

Another solution is using **localStorage** but yet doesn't seem ideal to me.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inject one service into another

```
@Injectable()
class Service2 {
  // constructor(private service2:Service2) {}
  // cyclic dependencies are not supported
  // therefore only one service can inject the other, 
  // but both directions at the same time causes an exception

  someProp:String = 'xxx';
}

@Injectable()
class Service1 {
  constructor(private service2:Service2) {
    console.log(service2.someProp);
  }
}
```

See also [DI with cyclic dependency with custom HTTP and ConfigService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233)

You can also use observables so that one service can subscribe to changes in the other service.