# How to use httpInterceptor and configService both at the same time in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

My Question is similar to this [DI with cyclic dependency with custom HTTP and ConfigService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice) but not exactly same and solution provided for this question does not solve the issue for me.

I am using httpInterceptor and also need configService to pull environment info at run time. Here is how it looks like:

```
//app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response,     XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { CacheService, CacheStoragesEnum } from 'ng2-cache/ng2-cache';

import { AppConfig }       from './app.config';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpInterceptorService}  from './services/http-interceptor/http-interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [    
    CacheService,
    AppConfig,        
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => config.load(), deps: [AppConfig]},
    { provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router, cacheService: CacheService,  appConfig: AppConfig) => return new HttpInterceptorService(backend, defaultOptions, router, cacheService, appConfig), deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, CacheService, AppConfig]}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.config.ts

```
//app.config.ts
import { Inject, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {

    private config: Object = null;
    private env:    Object = null;
    private http: Http;

    constructor(private injector : Injector) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('initialize http in appConfig');
        this.http = this.injector.get(Http);          
      });          
    }

    /**
     * Use to get the data found in the second file (config file)
     */
    public getConfig(key: any) {
        return this.config[key];
    }

    /**
     * Use to get the data found in the first file (env file)
     */
    public getEnv(key: any) {
        return this.env[key];
    }

        /**
     * This method:
     *   a) Loads "env.json" to get the current working environment (e.g.: 'production', 'development')
     *   b) Loads "config.[env].json" to get all env's variables (e.g.: 'config.development.json')
     */
    public load() {
        console.log('---------------------- in appConfig load method --------------------');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('app/env.json').map( res => res.json() ).catch((error: any):any => {
                console.log('Configuration file "env.json" could not be read');
                resolve(true);
                return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
            }).subscribe( (envResponse) => {
                this.env = envResponse;
                console.log('-------------------------------------------------');
                console.log(envResponse);

                let request:any = null;

                switch (envResponse['env']) {
                    case 'production': {
                        request = this.http.get('app/config.' + envResponse['env'] + '.json');
                    } break;

                    case 'test': {
                        request = this.http.get('app/config.' + envResponse['env'] + '.json');
                    } break;

                    case 'default': {
                        console.error('Environment file is not set or invalid');
                        resolve(true);
                    } break;
                }

                if (request) {
                    request
                        .map( res => res.json() )
                        .catch((error: any) => {
                            console.error('Error reading ' + envResponse['env'] + ' configuration file');
                            resolve(error);
                            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                        })
                        .subscribe((responseData) => {
                            this.config = responseData;
                            resolve(true);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.error('Env config file "env.json" is not valid');
                    resolve(true);
                }
            });

        });
    }
}
```

And here is interceptor

```
//http-interceptor.service.ts
import {Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams,ConnectionBackend, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {CacheService, CacheStoragesEnum} from 'ng2-cache/ng2-cache';

import { AppConfig } from '../../app.config';

const TOKEN_EXPIRY = '1440';
const CACHE_EXPIRY = 10 * 60 * 1000;
const CACHE_RECYCLE = 4 * 60 * 1000;

export class HttpInterceptorService extends Http {

  private webUrl : string;
  private serviceUrl : string;
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend,
                defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                private _router: Router,
                private _cacheService: CacheService,
              private config: AppConfig) {
      super(backend, defaultOptions);
      this._cacheService = this._cacheService.useStorage(CacheStoragesEnum.LOCAL_STORAGE);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.getToken(url).flatMap(tokenRecord =>super.request(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options)));

    }


    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      return this.getToken(url).flatMap(tokenRecord => super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options)))
    }

    post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      return this.getToken(url).flatMap(tokenRecord => super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options)))
    }

    put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.getToken(url).flatMap(tokenRecord => super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options)));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.getToken(url).flatMap(tokenRecord => super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options)));
    }

    getRequestOptionArgs(tokenRecord, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) : RequestOptionsArgs {
        if (options == null) {
            options = new RequestOptions();
        }

        if (options.headers == null) {
            options.headers = new Headers();
        }

        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        options.headers.append('Authorization', tokenRecord.token);

        return options;
    }

    getToken (url) {
      let domain;

      this.webUrl = this.config.getConfig('webUrl');
      this.serviceUrl = this.config.getConfig('serviceUrl');

      if (this.serviceUrl.indexOf("://") > -1) {
        domain = this.serviceUrl.split('/')[2];
      } else {
        domain = this.serviceUrl.split('/')[0];
      }
      domain = domain.split(':')[0];

      let serviceHost = domain;

      let headers = new Headers(); 
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*'); 
      let params = new URLSearchParams();

      params.append('service', serviceHost);
      params.append('expiry', TOKEN_EXPIRY);
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers, search:params, withCredentials:true });

      let cacheName = "webCache";
      let cacheKeyBase = "/token";
      let cacheKey = cacheKeyBase + "/" + serviceHost;

      let existingCache =  this._cacheService.get(cacheKey);
      if(existingCache) {
        return Observable.of(existingCache);

      }
      return super.get(this.webUrl+'/a/token', options)
      .map((response:Response) => {
        response = response.json();

        let tokenType = response['tokenType'];
        let tokenVal = response['access_token'];
        let token = tokenType + " " + tokenVal;
        let tokenRecord = {
            token:token,
            tokenType:response['tokenType'],
            expiresAt: new Date(response['expires_at'] * 1000),
            expiresIn: response['expires_in'],
            aquiredOn: new Date()
        };

        this._cacheService.set(cacheKey, tokenRecord, {maxAge: CACHE_EXPIRY});

        return tokenRecord;
      }).catch(this.handleError);

    }

    private handleError(error:Response){
      return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentTypes' of undefined
at setupRouter
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to solve the issue, this how I have injected appConfig

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response,     XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { CacheService, CacheStoragesEnum } from 'ng2-cache/ng2-cache';

import { AppConfig }       from './app.config';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpInterceptorService}  from './services/http-interceptor/http-interceptor.service';

export function createAppModule(conf) {
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [    
    CacheService,
   { provide: Config, useValue: conf },
    {
      provide: AppConfig,
      useFactory: (_config: Config) => {
        return new AppConfig(_config);
      }, deps: [Config]
    },
    { provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router, cacheService: CacheService,  appConfig: AppConfig) => return new HttpInterceptorService(backend, defaultOptions, router, cacheService, appConfig), deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, CacheService, AppConfig]}
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule { }
return AppModule;
}
```

I made the changes in main.ts to use AppModule and pulling config.json, here how it looks like

```js
import './polyfills.ts';
import { ReflectiveInjector, Injectable, OpaqueToken, Injector, NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {
  Http, CookieXSRFStrategy, XSRFStrategy, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions,
  ResponseOptions, BaseResponseOptions, XHRBackend, BrowserXhr, Response
} from '@angular/http';

import { createAppModule } from './app/app.module';

function getHttp(): Http {
  let providers = [
    {
      provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    BrowserXhr,
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },
    { provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions },
    XHRBackend
  ];
  return ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(providers).get(Http);
}

getHttp().get('/assets/config.json').toPromise()
  .then((res: Response) => {
    let conf = res.json();
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(createAppModule(conf));
  })
  .catch(error => { console.error(error) });
```

There might be better ways of doing this but I found this working for me but anyone has better approach and any suggestion then please provide your comments.

Comment: any follow up on this? I'm running into the same issue with Angular 6.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal I was not able to resolve this. Instead I ended up encrypting my secrets and committing them to source control. Before I deploy or start up my development server I decrypt the secrets for the environment I'm running in. Here's a gist that outlines the approach I'm using: https://gist.github.com/lucasklaassen/739181e621dcb187a1d0e08c82e8d9c6