# Angular 4 doesn't include headers to http request

Tags: angular

I am trying very simple angular 4 http request.
When i check chrome developer tools, i couldn't see http headers.

```
const headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer: 123213');
this.http.post('https://127.0.0.1:502', JSON.stringify(token), {headers: headers}).subscribe();
```

am i missing something?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41133924/2545680)

Comment: @Maximus just tried and it doesn't work. :/

Comment: I provided an example in my answer, just checked, it works for me, I'm using Angular v4.x

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Starting with `angular@5.x.` the `@angular/http` module is deprecated with all its classes. Now `angular/common/http` should be used. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/2545680) for more.

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

this.http.post(
   "http://localhost:3000/contacts",
   JSON.stringify({id: 4, name: 'some'}),
   httpOptions 
).subscribe();
```

For the older versions, you can do it like this:

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('authentication', `hello`);

       const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
       this.http.post(
           "http://localhost:3000/contacts",
           JSON.stringify({id: 4, name: 'some'}),
           options
       ).subscribe();
```

**You have to ensure** that you're importing correct objects from the `@angular/http`:

```
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
```

If you still don't see your headers, it's also possible that the server you're using doesn't allow them. When a browser makes a request to the other origin, it sends [access-control-headers-request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) header to check if server allows custom header. If your server is not configured to allow custom headers, you will not see them in the consequent requests.

Comment: According to [docs on Headers](https://angular.io/api/http/Headers), the class is deprecated and it's suggested to use the [class *HttpHeaders*](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders). I still can't make it work, though (something with the syntax that I'm too ignorant about) so if you would like to update your answer with the non-obsolete class, it would be heavily appreciated.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana, yes, the `@angular/http` module is deprecated with all its classes. Now `@angular/common/http` should be used. I'll add to the answer. Thanks

Comment: Headers is defunct. Use HttpHeaders instead.

Answer (score 19):

If you use HttpClient instead Http your code should looks like this:

```
login(credintials: Authenticate): Observable<any> {

    const body = {
        username: credintials.username,
        password: credintials.password,
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: credintials.client_id
    };
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic loremlorem');

    return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}/uaa/oauth/token`,
        body,
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    );
}
```

If your params is optional you should append params like this:

```
let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
if (param) {
  params = params.append( 'page', param.page );
}
```

Source code looks like:

```
/**
 * Construct a new body with an appended value for the given parameter name.
 */
append(param: string, value: string): HttpParams;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
            this.headers = new Headers();
            this.headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    }
```

and inside the method this

```
return this.http.post(url, jsonData, this.headers).map((resp: Response) => resp.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
};

"For httppost"

```
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost/rajat/ajax/contact_query_submit/',{name:name,email:email,phone:phone,message:message},httpOptions)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

"For receive post data you have to do this below mentioned"

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $_POST = json_decode($postdata,TRUE);
        $addArr = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
            'created' => time()
        );
```