# Difference between HttpModule and HttpClientModule

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular2-http

Which one is best to build a mock web service just for test purposes in Angular apps?

Comment: [*"HttpClient is an evolution of the existing Angular HTTP API, which exists
alongside of it in a separate package..."*](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/37797e2).

Comment: I actually wrote about some of its new features on my blog yesterday: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Jul/15/angular-http-client.html

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: The tutorial uses HttpModule and https://angular.io/guide/http uses HttpClientModule and neither explains when one or the other should be used or what version of Angular is needed to use what.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Use the `HttpClient` class from `HttpClientModule` if you're using Angular 4.3.x and above:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule
 ],
 ...

 class MyService() {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {...}
```

It's an upgraded version of `http` from `@angular/http` module with the following improvements:

> - Interceptors allow middleware logic to be inserted into the pipeline
> - Immutable request/response objects
> - Progress events for both request upload and response download

You can read about how it works in [Insider’s guide into interceptors and HttpClient mechanics in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf).

> - Typed, synchronous response body access, including support for JSON body types
> - JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed
> - Post-request verification & flush based testing framework

Going forward the old http client will be deprecated. Here are the links to the [commit message](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/37797e2) and [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Also pay attention that old http was injected using `Http` class token instead of the new `HttpClient`:

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule
 ],
 ...

 class MyService() {
    constructor(http: Http) {...}
```

Also, new `HttpClient` seem to require `tslib` in runtime, so you have to install it `npm i tslib` and update `system.config.js` if you're using `SystemJS`:

```js
map: {
     ...
    'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
```

And you need to add another mapping if you use SystemJS:

```js
'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
```

Comment: I am trying to import HttpClientModule. But '@angular/common/http' is not present in node_modules directory which I installed using "npm start" command. Can you help?

Comment: @DheerajKumar, which version are you using? it's only available in 4.3.0 and up

Comment: I downloaded angular quick start from git. and In package.json, "@angular/common": "^4.3.0" is present. but there is no @angular/common/http.

Comment: remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again

Comment: @Maxiums. npm install fails with error. Can you guide me where can I get fresh version of angular 4.3??

Comment: @DheerajKumar, if you're just learning Angular, you can use [this setup](https://github.com/maximusk/angular-seed). Otherwise you may be better off with using AngularCLI

Comment: I tried your code. Browser wont startup on np_start. When I goto localhost:\3000. It doesnt load appComponene.t, just index.html. I dont know why its so hard to get a 4.3 angular working :(

Comment: @DheerajKumar, can you create a separate question maybe? The community might help

Comment: I've run into this very same issue (I am using System.js).
One thing that is missing from this answer is that you'll also need to map the new module in system.js as follows:

`'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',`

Comment: I'm trying to set up an app built with the tour of heroes tutorial to use HttpClient. I've set everything up properly as far as I can tell, but when I attempt to run the simplest possible unit test, I get an error stating that tslib is missing. It's not. And I'm pointing to it in systemjs as shown above...

Comment: I upgrated to v7.2.15 and still i can use HttpModule but don't forget that angular recommends to use HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 44):

Don't want to be repetitive, but just to summarize in other way (features added in new HttpClient):

- Automatic conversion from JSON to an object
- Response type definition
- Event firing
- Simplified syntax for headers
- Interceptors

I wrote an article, where I covered the difference between old "http" and new "HttpClient". The goal was to explain it in the easiest way possible.

[Simply about new HttpClient in Angular](https://skryvets.com/blog/2017/11/26/simply-about-new-httpclient-in-angular/)

Answer (score 21):

This is a good [reference](https://blog.hackages.io/angular-http-httpclient-same-but-different-86a50bbcc450), it helped me switch my `http` requests to `httpClient`.

It compares the two in terms of differences and gives code examples.

This is just a few differences I dealt with while changing services to httpclient in my project (borrowing from the article I mentioned) :

### Importing

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

### Requesting and parsing response:

#### @angular/http

```
 this.http.get(url)
      // Extract the data in HTTP Response (parsing)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json() as GithubUser)
      .subscribe((data: GithubUser) => {
        // Display the result
        console.log('TJ user data', data);
      });
```

#### @angular/common/http

```
 this.http.get(url)
      .subscribe((data: GithubUser) => {
        // Data extraction from the HTTP response is already done
        // Display the result
        console.log('TJ user data', data);
      });
```

**Note:** You no longer have to extract the returned data explicitly; by default, if the data you get back is type of JSON, then you don't have to do anything extra.

But, if you need to parse any other type of response like text or blob, then make sure you add the `responseType` in the request. Like so:

### Making the GET HTTP request with `responseType` option:

```
 this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // Data extraction from the HTTP response is already done
        // Display the result
        console.log('TJ user data', data);
      });
```

### Adding Interceptor

I also used interceptors for adding the token for my authorization to every request, [reference](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/07/19/angular-2-new-http-interface-with-interceptors/).

like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyFirstInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private currentUserService: CurrentUserService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // get the token from a service
        const token: string = this.currentUserService.token;

        // add it if we have one
        if (token) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
        }

        // if this is a login-request the header is 
        // already set to x/www/formurl/encoded. 
        // so if we already have a content-type, do not 
        // set it, but if we don't have one, set it to 
        // default --> json
        if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        // setting the accept header
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

Its a pretty nice upgrade!

Comment: You need to include the relevant information in your answer and not just as a link

Answer (score 1):

There is a library which allows you to **use HttpClient with strongly-typed callbacks**.

The data and the error are available directly via these callbacks.

### [image: A reason for existing]

When you use HttpClient with Observable, you have to use **.subscribe(x=>...)** in the rest of your code.

This is because **Observable<`HttpResponse`<`T`>>** is tied to **HttpResponse**.

This **tightly couples** the **http layer** with the **rest of your code**.

This library encapsulates the **.subscribe(x => ...)** part and exposes only the data and error through your Models.

**With strongly-typed callbacks, you only have to deal with your Models in the rest of your code.**

The library is called **angular-extended-http-client**.

[**angular-extended-http-client library on GitHub**](https://github.com/VeritasSoftware/angular-http-client-ext)

[**angular-extended-http-client library on NPM**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-extended-http-client)

Very easy to use.

### Sample usage

The strongly-typed callbacks are

Success:

- **IObservable<`T`>**
- **IObservableHttpResponse**
- **IObservableHttpCustomResponse<`T`>**

Failure:

- **IObservableError<`TError`>**
- **IObservableHttpError**
- **IObservableHttpCustomError<`TError`>**

#### Add package to your project and in your app module

```js
import { HttpClientExtModule } from 'angular-extended-http-client';
```

and in the @NgModule imports

```js
  imports: [
    .
    .
    .
    HttpClientExtModule
  ],
```

#### Your Models

```js
//Normal response returned by the API.
export class RacingResponse {
    result: RacingItem[];
}

//Custom exception thrown by the API.
export class APIException {
    className: string;
}
```

#### Your Service

In your Service, you just create params with these callback types.

Then, pass them on to the **HttpClientExt**'s get method.

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core'
import { RacingResponse, APIException } from '../models/models'
import { HttpClientExt, IObservable, IObservableError, ResponseType, ErrorType } from 'angular-extended-http-client';
.
.

@Injectable()
export class RacingService {

    //Inject HttpClientExt component.
    constructor(private client: HttpClientExt, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig) {

    }

    //Declare params of type IObservable<T> and IObservableError<TError>.
    //These are the success and failure callbacks.
    //The success callback will return the response objects returned by the underlying HttpClient call.
    //The failure callback will return the error objects returned by the underlying HttpClient call.
    getRaceInfo(success: IObservable<RacingResponse>, failure?: IObservableError<APIException>) {
        let url = this.config.apiEndpoint;

        this.client.get(url, ResponseType.IObservable, success, ErrorType.IObservableError, failure);
    }
}
```

#### Your Component

In your Component, your Service is injected and the **getRaceInfo** API called as shown below.

```js
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.service.getRaceInfo(response => this.result = response.result,
                                error => this.errorMsg = error.className);

  }
```

Both, **response** and **error** returned in the callbacks are strongly typed. Eg. **response** is type **RacingResponse** and **error** is **APIException**.

You only deal with your Models in these strongly-typed callbacks.

Hence, The rest of your code only knows about your Models.

Also, you can still use the traditional route and return Observable<`HttpResponse<`T`>`> from Service API.

Answer (score 0):

**HttpClient** is a new API that came with 4.3, it has updated API's with support for progress events, json deserialization by default, Interceptors and many other great features. See more here ***https://angular.io/guide/http***

**Http** is the older API and will eventually be deprecated.

Since their usage is very similar for basic tasks I would advise using HttpClient since it is the more modern and easy to use alternative.