# Synchronous Reponse body access HttpClient Angular 4

Tags: angular, httpclient

What is Synchronous response body access in Angular 4 HTTPClient and how is this thing implemented?

Comment: where did you read it?

Comment: it's a new feature in HTTPClient Module in Angular 4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4 mentioned here and https://netbasal.com/a-taste-from-the-new-angular-http-client-38fcdc6b359b here. I am going through new features in HTTPClient added to angular 4.