# Cannot find the '@angular/common/http' module

Tags: angular, node-modules

I am following [this](https://angular.io/guide/http) fundamental tutorial on Angular about Http.

As one can see in the "Setup: Installing the module" section, they import the HttpClientModule as follow:

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

When I try this in my project, I get the following error: "Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'".

I have tried importing the following module, as follow:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

And then my imports section:

```
imports: [
    HttpModule
],
```

The problem now is, I cannot inject this HttpModule into my service object, and I get the following error: "Cannot find module HttpModule".

Here is my service class:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//Custom Models
import { Feed } from '../Models/Feed';

@Injectable()
export class FeedsService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpModule) {}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
All I should have done when I realized I could not import the module as per the tutorial, was to run the `npm update` command, to update all my packages.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/2545680) for the difference between `Http` and `HttpClient`

Comment: On Angular 11 I solved this problem deleting node_modules folder and run 
`npm install`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Important**: `HttpClientModule` is for Angular 4.3.0 and above. Check [**@Maximus'**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545680/maximus) comments and [**@Pengyy's**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579471/pengyy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207906/5706293) for more info.

---

Original answer:

You need to inject `HttpClient` in your component/service not the module. If you import `HttpClientModule` in your `@NgModule`

```
// app.module.ts:
 
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
 
// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

So change

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpModule) {}
```

to

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

as it's been written in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data)

---

However, since you imported the HttpModule

you need to inject `constructor(private httpClient: Http)` as [**@Maximus**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545680/maximus) stated in the comments and [**@Pengyy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7579471/pengyy) in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207906/5706293).

And for more info on differences between `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/5706293)

Comment: This does not work: If I follow their tutorial, I cannot import this: import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';  I don't have that common/http module.  Where can I find it

Comment: it's just `Http` - `constructor(private httpClient: Http)` since he's importing `'@angular/http'`, not `'@angular/common/http'`

Comment: @monstertjie_za Maximus is right you are importing `HttpModule` but trying to use  `HttpClient` you need to select 1

Comment: @Maximus if you put down an answer I'll delete mine and upvote yours :)

Comment: @echonax, upvote mine next time) just edit the answer and add details about httpClient and http

Comment: I have installed version 4.3.5 of @angular/common and there doesn't appear to be an http folder under node_modules/@angular/common. As a result, my import statement doesn't work: import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; fails with cannot find module "@angular/common/http". I have already deleted and npm installed again, and done an npm update. Still no http folder. Why can I not see it?

Comment: @tone if you've done the installation corrrectly, it should've been there as in the official github package: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/common/http. Have you checked it from your folder directory?

Comment: Argh. I just deleted it again and did another npm update and it has turned up. Weird.

Comment: @tone "stuff" happens :-) glad you figured it out

Answer (score 43):

**Important Update:**

`HttpModule` and `Http` from `@angular/http` has been **deprecated since Angular V5**, should of using `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` instead, refer **[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-code)**.

---

For Angular version **previous from **@4.3.0**, You should inject `Http` from `@angular/http`, and `HttpModule` is for importing at your NgModule's import array.

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [HttpModule]
})
```

Inject `http` at component or service

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

---

For Angular version **after(include) 4.3.0**, you can use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` instead of `Http` from `@angular/http`. Don't forget to import `HttpClientModule` at your `NgModule`'s import array first.

Refer @echonax's answer.

Comment: You are the first one who posted a solution that helped me, thanks.

Comment: @echonax Okay, where is the module, I cannot find it?

Comment: @echonax Just a suggestion. BTW I didn't know any thing about `HttpClient`, or maybe I missed it, but still didn't find it after a little quick research. can u give me a link?

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/2545680) for the difference between `Http` and `HttpClient`

Comment: @Maximus great! sorry for  I didn't follow the change log for a while.

Comment: @Pengyy, Angular is very dynamic)

Comment: @Pengyy I am sorry, but I will accept another answer here, and deselect yours

Comment: @monstertjie_za that's ok. feel free since that answer is more up to date.

Answer (score 4):

## note: This is for @angular/http, not the asked @angular/common/http!

Just import in this way, WORKS perfectly:

```
// Import HttpModule from @angular/http
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HelloIonicPage,
    ItemDetailsPage,
    ListPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [... ]
})
```

and then you contruct in the service.ts like this:

```
constructor(private http: Http) { }

getmyClass(): Promise<myClass[]> {
  return this.http.get(URL)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json().data as myClass[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<IEmployee[]>'.

Answer (score 1):

I was using http in angular 5 that was a problem.
Using Httpclient resolved the issue.

Comment: not necessarily the same version. Change to some old version and it'll work.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using Angular 5. I suppose there may have been some bug fixes under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of auto imports. my HTTP_INTERCEPTORS was auto imported like this:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http/src/interceptor';
```

instead of

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
```

which caused this error

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are out of date once again. To resolve this I had to do:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        HttpClient
    ],
```

all of this inside the `app.module.ts`. this is for angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

You should import `http` from `@angular/http` in your service:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

constructor(private http: http) {} // <--Then Inject it here


// now you can use it in any function eg:
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('whateverURL');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Ionic 3 and Angular 5, I had the same error pop up and I didn't find any solutions here. But I did find some steps that worked for me.

Steps to reproduce:

- npm install -g cordova ionic
- ionic start myApp tabs
- cd myApp
- cd node_modules/angular/common (no http module exists).

ionic:(run ionic info from a terminal/cmd prompt), check versions and make sure they're up to date. You can also check the angular versions and packages in the package.json folder in your project.

I checked my dependencies and packages and installed cordova. Restarted atom and the error went away. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this:
**http:** deprecate @angular/http in favor of @angular/common/http.

Answer (score 0):

When adding any dependency and getting this error

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: matrimonial-ui@0.0.0 npm ERR!
> Found: @angular/core@14.2.12 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core npm
> ERR!   @angular/core@"^14.2.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"7.2.16"
> from @angular/http@7.2.16 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/http npm ERR!
> @angular/http@"7.2.16" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!  npm ERR! npm ERR!
> For a full report see: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-05T17_55_53_622Z-eresolve-report.txt
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-05T17_55_53_622Z-debug-0.log

You can force clear the cache by running run `npm cache clean --force`