# Angular2 - Unable to import http module

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, angular-httpclient

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207906/3317808) did not help me import http module without error.

---

```
$ ng version
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 6.11.5
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.0
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
$
```

---

Below code,

```
/* ../src/app/app.module.ts */
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DirectoryComponent,
    FilterPipe,
    LoggingService
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

and service code,

```
/*  ../src/app/data.service.ts */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

}
```

---

gives error:

```
ERROR in src/app/data.service.ts(2,9): error TS2305: Module '"/home/../My_Websites/Youtube_sites/angular_2_playlist/ninja-directory/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpClient'.
```

---

Why `HttpClient` service cannot be injected in the constructor of service code?

Comment: what is the version of angular you are using

Comment: The error `node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member` states that you'are importing it from other place

Comment: Are you using Systemjs?

Comment: @yurzui What is Systemjs? this is new for me

Comment: @yurzui how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your services in app.component.ts

```
import {DataService} from './data.service.ts';
```

> and also give in your **app.component.ts** file

```
providers:[DataService]
```

[See TutorialsPoint Example for More](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular2/angular2_services.htm)

**Thanks**

Comment: What does `providers` and `bootstrap` signify? What is their purpose?