# primeng gives Cannot find module '@angular/http'

Tags: angular, jhipster, primeng

I'm using [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) to develop a Spring-Boot+Angular app. However, I'm getting this error while using primeng 5.6.0 with angular 5.6.0 in my  project:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./src/main/webapp/app/primeng/data/datascroller/datascrollerdemo.module.ts:4:28
>       TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.

Any help would be approeciated.

Comment: `@angular/http` has been deprecated since 5.0.0. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207615/cannot-find-the-angular-common-http-module/45207906#45207906 and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find the '@angular/common/http' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207615/cannot-find-the-angular-common-http-module)

Answer (score 5):

Run the command

```
npm install @angular/http --save
```

and restart your application.

Basically, there is HTTP package is missing in your project so it is throwing this error

## Update

As you are using Angular 5.6.0 it should be `HttpClientModule` since `HttpModule` is deprecated in previous versions of Angular

Comment: OP is using angular 5.6.0 should not it be `HttpClientModule` since `HttpModule` is deprecated

Comment: yes @Vikas you are right , Thanks I'll Update my answer