# what's the difference between HttpModule and HttpClientModule in Angular2?

Tags: angular, http

I am new in Angular2 and I am learning to make http calls.

I have found Angular2 has these two modules:

> HttpModule from @angular/http

and

> HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http

and they both support http calls.

However I don't figure out the difference between them.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a new API that came with 4.3, it has updated API's with support for progress events, json deserialization by default, Interceptors and many other great features. See more here https://angular.io/guide/http

`Http` is the older API and will eventually be deprecated.

Since their usage is very similar for basic tasks I would advise using HttpClient since it is the more modern and easy to use alternative.

Comment: I replaced my `Http` with the newer `HttpClient`. Thanks.