# angular 2 error httpcliendmodule

Tags: angular

[image]have some error with httpclientmodule:
i have app.module.ts and there is code :

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule  } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule  ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and error: 
nodemodules/@angular/http/http  has no exported member 'HttpClientModule'

Comment: see [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be imported from `@angular/common/http`

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Make sure you have installed **angular@^4.3.0** ([changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#430-2017-07-14))

See also the docs

- https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-installing-the-module

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IRXL1vSX7hGXjBI0K43R?p=preview)**

Comment: i tried it, but there is error: cannot find module  '@angular/common/http'

Comment: @shoopik Which angular version are you using?

Comment: mm, how can i check it ?  in json i see next:  "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",

Comment: @shoopik You have to upgrade your version

Comment: can you tell me how to do it ?))

Comment: Replace all `"~4.0.0"` with `"~4.3.0"`. Remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`

Comment: now i have errors with system.js, before update that was ok

Comment: @shoopik Check `config.js` from https://plnkr.co/edit/foQNdnt5CRmzpnBuInfT or config from my repo https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/blob/master/systemjs.config.js

Comment: oh, still have errors, but when  i delete httpcliendmodue it works

Comment: Try adding `'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',` and `'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',`

Comment: i dont know whats wrong, but there is bunch of errors with zone.js

Comment: @shoopik I need some reproduction. Maybe you can setup minimal github repo?

Comment: i delete systemjs.config and now it works without httpclientmodule, and dont with it

Comment: by the way, i put my config.js because it works without httpclientmodule, when i put your config.js it doesnt work even wtihout

Comment: @shoopik I don't see where you added `'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js'`, and `'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js'`  Don't forget `npm i --save tslib`. After that your repo works for me

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! but why it worked without tslib when i didnt type httpclientmodule, how is it depends

Comment: `common-http.umd.js` bundle requires it as dependency. Maybe it will be changed soon https://github.com/angular/common-builds/blob/4.3.0/bundles/common-http.umd.js#L7