# error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' for HttpClientModule

Tags: angular, import

I am trying to import HttpClientModule using the following line in my app.module.ts:

> import { HttpClientModule }     from '@angular/common/http';

and

```
imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
]
```

However I keep getting the same error:

> src/app/app.module.ts(4,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http'.

Despite those exact lines being included in these tutorials:

- https://angular.io/guide/http
- https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b
- http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2017/07/17/http-client-module/

How can I fix this and use HttpClient ?

Comment: you need to use version above 4.3

Comment: @echonax, let's see if it fixes the error)

Comment: is that someone me ? :P just kidding

Comment: @Sajeetharan hahaha it could be anyone and not that it's illegal or anything :-)

Comment: How can I update to the latest version ? `npm update` didn't fix anything; do I need to edit package.json, or do something else ?

Comment: @echonax, yeah, I will

Comment: @user96649 Yes, change all the `@angular`-lines to this version: `"@angular/common": "^4.3.4"`, then run `npm install`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new http client was only added in the `4.3` version. You're probably using older angular version. You need to update the project. Go into `package.json` and modify all `@angular/...` entries to include `^4.3.4` version.

Also, if you're using SystemJS you need to add two entries to the `map`:

```
'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
```

Also see [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865)

Comment: This remove the error in the log, but now I get a XHR Error from the app: `Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http as "@angular/common/http" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js`

Comment: @user96649, do you use `systemjs`?

Comment: No, I installed by git cloning, and using npm install.

Comment: look for `systemjs.config.js` file and add `'@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js',`

Comment: Still no success: `Error loading http://localhost:3000/tslib as "tslib" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js`

Comment: you have to install it `npm i tslib` and update `systemjs.config.js` with  `'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js'`

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot ! You should probably add these details to the main answer. Why there is no information on any tutorial that it's needed to install with npm or update systemjs, that is a mystery.