# res.json() is a not a function in HttpClient Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I was using Angular `Http` module before and the method `res.json()` used to work fine.
I have recently tried `HttpClient` but then the `res.json()` dosen't seem to work . only using `res` works can some one tell me what changed has happened in the http client.

```
return this.client.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
              .map((res:Response) => {
                 return  res.json(); // using maps to filter data returned form the http call this json dosn't work with http client
              }).map(data => {
                return data; // using maps of maps to filter data returned form the map
        }).flatMap((jedi) => this.http.get(jedi['homeworld'])
          .map(res => {
           return res.json().name; // using flat maps to combine data returned from two observables into one
          }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')));
```

I switched to http client because of the new interceptor can pointers are welcomed thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, that's because new http client by default calls `res.json()` implicitly and you don't need to that manually yourself. Here is the quote from commit:

> JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed

See [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/2545680) for more details.

Comment: ohh thats whats chabged thanks. So it always better now to use httpclien instead of http right?

Comment: @INFOSYS, yes, I believe so. It has many advantages. Check the answer I linked.

Answer (score 0):

As HttpClient itself adds res.json(), which means it implicitly calls this function due to which, it is worthless to call it explicitly or manually. So there is no need to add this function. Hope this works, thanx...

Comment: Please highlight the additional insight of your answer as compared to the existing, accepted and upvoted one.

Comment: Dear Yunnosch, there is nothing much to add into it, its that simple. I think the only pertinent factor in this answer is not to use .json() as it works automatically with HttpClient over simple http request.