# rxjs map is giving an error when i upgrade http to httpClient in angular7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-httpclient

I have a service in which I have login function like this

```
public userLogin(body) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apiService
    .generateApiRequest({
      route: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.route,
      type: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.type,
      body: body
    })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(response => {
      resolve(response);
     });
   });
 }
```

and have `generateApiRequest` function in utilities like this

```
generateApiRequest(request, isTokened = false) {
    var res;
    let response;
    if (!request.headers) {
        request.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    }
    if (isTokened) {
        request.headers.append('Token', this.localCache.getToken());
    }
    switch (request.type) {
        case Constants.REQUEST_TYPE.GET:
            response = this.get(request);
            break;
        case Constants.REQUEST_TYPE.POST:
            response = this.post(request);
            break;
        case Constants.REQUEST_TYPE.PUT:
            response = this.put(request);
            break;
        case Constants.REQUEST_TYPE.DELETE:
            response = this.delete(request);
            break;
    }
    return response;
}
```

When I upgraded older `http` to new `HttpClient` so after this I have to change map inside pipe function so I did like this

```
public userLogin(body) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apiService
    .generateApiRequest({
      route: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.route,
      type: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.type,
      body: body
    })
    .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
    .subscribe(response => {
      resolve(response);
     });
  });
 }
```

But compiler is giving an error at this line `.pipe(map(res => res.json()))`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Now you already got an answer, but for the future, please post the error you get as well. "compiler is giving an error" isn't always enough information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, that's because new http client by default calls res.json() implicitly and you don't need to that manually yourself. Just remove .json() call, so you don't need to use 'map' at all in your case.

Comment: If you are going to copy paste part of someone elses answer, please give the credits... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780553/6294072

Comment: So should i replace this `.pipe(map(res => res.json()))` to `.pipe()` ?

Comment: It should work, but you can also remove the whole line

Comment: You don't need to use .pipe() at all, just leave only .subscribe with your code.

Comment: you mean this `.generateApiRequest({
          route: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.route,
          type: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.type,
          body: body
        })
        .subscribe(response => {
          resolve(response);
        });`  

Instead of    
`.generateApiRequest({
          route: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.route,
          type: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.type,
          body: body
        })
        .pipe(map(res => res.json()))
        .subscribe(response => {
          resolve(response);
        });`

Comment: Yeah, definitely

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular Http client already map response from API by default is JSON.

You can simply remove the map

```
public userLogin(body) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apiService
    .generateApiRequest({
      route: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.route,
      type: Constants.API_ROUTES.USER_LOGIN.type,
      body: body
    })
    .subscribe(response => {
      resolve(response);
     });
  });
 }
```