# ngx-translate/core "Error: No provider for HttpClient!"

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I've downloaded the package ngx-translate/core, and been following the documentation instructions.

I can't get the translation to work.
The steps i made:

1] define everything in the AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

import { routing } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

    @NgModule({
     declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2] define everything in AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  param = { value: 'world' };

  constructor(private router: Router, translate: TranslateService) {
    // this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    translate.use('en');
  }
}
```

3] the html

```
<div>{{ 'HELLO' | translate:param }}</div>
```

4] And finally created in the assets/i18n/en.json

```
{
    "HELLO": "Hi There"
}
```

I keep getting these errors in the screen shot below
[image: Errors the popup in the browser console]

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Yiu are missing `HttpClientModule` from your app imports.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This `ngx-translate/core` uses the latest `HttpClientModule` instead of the old `HttpModule` change the following in the imports array in `NgModule`

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule, // the change from http module
    routing,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ]
```

See [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/2545680) for more details.

Comment: Amazing, just added "HttpClientModule" and it worked like a charm. magic . from the harry potter series.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts, to prevent injector provider error. In standalone, you can just add the HttpClientModule in the imports of the decorator of the app.component.ts, this should solve the issue