# getting a object with HttpClient angular 4 and call it a component

Tags: angular

I am out of practice and trying to brush up on Angular. I want to return an object and render it in the HTML file.

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class NameService {

    url:string = "";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


    public getActivities(): Observable<UserModel> {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }


}
```

component:

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {

    users:UserModel;

  constructor(private nameService: NameService) { }

  public getUsers(){
      this.users = this.nameService.getActivities()
          .subscribe(res => {this.users = res});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getUsers();
  }
```

error `Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'UserModel'.`

and

`Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserModel>'.`

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index">
            {{i + 1}} - {{user.id}}
            {{i + 1}} - {{user.first_name}}
            {{i + 1}} - {{user.last_name}}
            {{i + 1}} - {{user.email}}
            {{i + 1}} - {{user.ip}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and the JSON:

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "first_name": "Blakelee",
    "last_name": "Gillingham",
    "email": "bgillinghama@engadget.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "234.175.225.8"
}, {
    "id": 12,
    "first_name": "Tally",
    "last_name": "Loraine",
    "email": "tloraineb@marriott.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "ip_address": "50.20.33.244"
},
```

I am using Angular 5 but using angular 4 practices because it will break my other application in do so.

-----------------Update 1-------------------

I added `users:UserModel[]=[];`

[image]

Then I added

```
public getActivities(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<UserModel[]>(this.url);
    }
```

The ide stopped complaining but now I am back the the error:

`No provider for HttpHandler!`

------------------Edit 2------------------------

[image]

Comment: Hey man, mind marking answer if (either) helped? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that what `HttpClient` returns is an `Object`, so the error message is correct. You want to tell Angular that your response is of type `UserModel`, not of type `Object`. Besides that, you are getting an Array of `UserModel`'s (I assume it's a typo in your question). So your request should look like this:

```ts
public getActivities(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<UserModel[]>(this.url);
}
```

Also your subscribe in component would look like Sajeetharan pointed out:

```ts
public getUsers(){
  this.nameService.getActivities()
    .subscribe(res => this.users = res);
}
```

EDIT: And in component declare your `users` as

```ts
users:UserModel[] = [];
```

Read more about the (not so new) `HttpClient` and typechecking:  https://angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response

EDIT 2:

As for the followup error, make sure you have imported the correct module (`HttpClientModule`) and declared it right after `BrowserModule`: [Error: No provider for HttpHandler in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000748/error-no-provider-for-httphandler-in-angular2)

Comment: I did this and now it says `No provider for HttpHandler!` and I added it to the module too. Thank you for the help. Where is the cat?

Comment: ` Property 'id' is missing in type 'UserModel[]'.` and Type 'Observable<UserModel[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserModel>

Comment: You are still having typing issues, see that you have on all places marked the incoming data as `<UserModel[]>`. The other one is marked as an OBJECT of type `UserModel`. And my kitties are doing fine thanks :D Sleeping somewhere, preparing themselves for their nightly adventures (it's night soon on this side of the world)

Comment: You had the component variable `users` declared as an object, mark it as `users:UserModel[];` instead (updated answer)

Comment: Have you also updated the service? Declared `<UserModel[]>` on both the return type and the get request? This should work and not spit out such errors if all your types match.

Comment: Check this according to your error now, that you have imported correct module and that it's on the correct place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001121/7741865

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158537/discussion-between-drew1208-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 0):

Change it as following,

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit {

    users:UserModel[]=[];

  constructor(private nameService: NameService) { }

  public getUsers(){
     this.nameService.getActivities()
          .subscribe(res => {this.users = res});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getUsers();
  }
```

Comment: `Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserModel>'.` and it says `Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'id' is missing in type 'Object'.`

Comment: what about the udpated answer

Comment: ` Type 'UserModel' is not assignable to type 'UserModel[]'.`

Comment: so its not an array,try  users:UserModel=[];

Comment: you are missing something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158533/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-drew1208).