# Angular HttpClient vs Angular Http

Tags: angular, http

The introduction of the [HttpClient API](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) in angular 4.1 along with the other [Http API](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) is confusing.

They both serve the same purpose and yet they are put in 2 separate packages.

Is there a possibility that Http gets deprecated in favor of HttpClient (similarly to what happened with [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) and [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2))?

Has there been any announcement from the angular team on this?

P.S: Please note that my question concerns only the deprecation possibility of Http, and not any technical implementation related to HttpClient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

Comment: The two questions are entirely different. I'm asking about the deprecation possibility and not about any technical implementation like in the link that you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Not that there is possibility but `HttpModule` will get deprecated in favour of new `HttpClient`.
And yes, you should either start using `HttpClient` right away if you are starting new project or migrate to it if you have older projects that use `HttpModule`

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/37797e2