# HttpClient from @angular/common/http

Tags: angular

I'm sending a request with HttpClient and I'm unable to parse the response.
With http from @angular/http it isn't a problem to call response.json().token but this doesn't exist on HttpClient.

Here my request:

```
 return this.httpClient.post(environment.baseUrl + '/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {

//response.json() --> leads to an exception
...
```

the response is:
{response = {"token": "abcd...xyz"}}

Is it not possible to use HttpClient for this?

Comment: why not use the normal http then?

Comment: The default is `response.json()` in HttpClient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the old `Http` service, the new `HttpClient` service tries to guess the content type and parse it accordingly, so you don't need to call `response.json()` because `response` is already an object.