# Unable to access properties of an object returned from Observable in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an interface defining my data object as below:

```
  export interface Iemployee  {
    fileName: string;
    empData: IempData }
      export interface IempData {
    data: string;
  }
```

I was trying to retrieve a json object using observables .I could successfully load the object but unable to access any of the properties. I could see the object log in console ,but when I try to log the property I see undefined error.Also I could access properties during runtime in debug window but cant assign to a variable.Please help. Below is my service and component code.

Service Code:

```
downloadFile(): Observable<Iemployee > {       
    return this._http.get<Iemployee >(this._url)
        .map(response => {                
         return response as Iemployee;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Component Code:

```
downLoadFile() {

    this._employeeService.downloadFile().subscribe(response => {       
       this.empData = response;
       console.log(response );// object logged successfully
       console.log(response.fileName); // undefined but can see it during debugging with a watch
       console.log(this.empData ); //can log 
       console.log(this.empData .fileName);// undefined

    }, Error => {
      console.log(Error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` print? `as IEda` doesn't add any properties. That's only a hint for the tools like auto-completion and compiler.

Comment: Are you using `http` or `httpclient`? [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4). With `http` the body of the response can be found on property `data`. With `HttpClient` the body is returned directly in the resulting object.

Comment: Im really sorry Its a typo in my question. I was trying to cast  to Iemployee type.Also I was trying to log this.empData in console. Im using HttpClient in my service.Also as a intial step Im loading data from a static json file.

Comment: Console.log (response) is printing the object perfectly, but when I try to log the response.fileName its showing undefined

Comment: `Console.log (response) is printing the object perfectly` <= I do not see that line in your code above, please add it as well as the output that is printed.   `log the response.fileName its showing undefined` <= I also do not see this in your code above, please add it.

Comment: Im sorry im unable to edit the question but here is my component code :
downLoadFile() {

this._employeeService.downloadFile().subscribe(response => {       
   this.empData = response;
   console.log(response); // Object logged
   console.log(response.fileName); // undefined error
   console.log(this.empData); //object logged but cant load properties


}, Error => {
  console.log(Error);
});

Comment: `Im sorry im unable to edit the question` <= You can always edit your own question. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46847777/edit)  link underneath your question content and tags.

Comment: Sorry for too many comments .Since this is my first question ,I could not edit it .But the link worked. I edited the question .Please revisit