# how http, httpClient, httpModule and httpClientModule differ with each other?

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

Can you please let me know how `http`, `httpClient`, `httpModule` and `httpClientModule` differ with each other? which among them are depricated and supported versions of each of them.

Comment: Can you share your own understanding of all these and tell us what's confusing you in them?

Comment: @maheshpeddi i think you have go through with this answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896012/what-are-advantages-of-angular-5-httpclient-over-previous-http

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK http and httpModule were the ones used before the introduction of an improved version: the httpClient and httpClientModule.

Both ara available for compatibility reasons, but http and httpModule are deprecated (they will disappear from Angular after a while) so if you are in a brand new project, use the newer and more powerful Module instead.

Hope this helps!