# Migrating from @angular/http to @angular/common/http

Tags: angular-cli, angular-httpclient

I am migrating an angular-cli application from "@angular/http" to "@angular/common/http" but are having a some problems getting it to work.

I have a function that makes a request against my API and get the following json back.

```
{"Categories":[
   {"name":"my first category","routetype":"category"},
   {"name":"my second category","routetype":"category"}
]}
```

I am mapping that to class

```
export class Category {
    name: string;
    routetype: string;
}
```

Current code (working):

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
...
getCategories(context: SiteContext): Observable<Array<Category>> {
    return this.http.get(routes.getCategories(context), { cache: true })
      .map((res: Response) => <Array<Category>>res.json().Categories)
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

New code (Not working).

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
getCategories(context: SiteContext): Observable<Array<Category>> {
    return this.httpClient.cache().get(routes.getCategories(context))
      .map((res: Response) => <Array<Category>>res.json().Categories)
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

In vs.code I get this error message:

```
[ts] Property 'Categories' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'
```

on this line:

```
.map((res: Response) => <Array<Category>>res.json().Categories)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular 4.3+ [HttpClient has a completely different API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865). It already does the json parsing for you.

So your code should look more like:

```
this.httpClient.get<Categories>().map(data => data.Categories).do(data => console.log(data).catch(this.handlError);
```

(Your Response type belongs to the old API)

Comment: Got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

What was a great help for me while doing the equivalent migration, was generating a small [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/) test project and analyzing how the jhipster entities are generated using the new HttpClient. Not exacly an answer but might help.