# Could using @angular/http and @angular/common/http at the same time cause problems in an Angular ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, angular

When I import:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

And then:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

this.httpClient.post(...
this.http.post(...
```

In this case, I use Microsoft Identity, which relies on cookies for authentication.

Could that cause problems if I post, for example, the login in one way and the register in another?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use old, deprecated `Http` when you can use `HttpClient`?
[Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

Comment: I started writing my application the old way and discovered the new one later, so i wonder if i should edit all or if it does not matter?

Comment: I would suggest you should edit this because when something is deprecated there is possibility that it will be removed in some future release. And I don't think it's a lot of work - of course depends on your project. But... it could still work. Depends on you.