# Having this error while displaying list of data in Angular => ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: json, angular, routes, frontend

I'm new in Angular and I have an error need to fix. This is the error I've encountered when I'm trying to display a list of data from jsonplaceholder. I don't know what is wrong in the code. May I ask for a help guys? Thank you.

> **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**
>       at RecipeService.push../src/app/recipes/recipe.service.ts.RecipeService.getRecipe
>   (**recipe.service.ts:25**)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (**recipe-detail.component.ts:26**)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:134)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   (Subscriber.js:77)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe
>   (BehaviorSubject.js:22)
>       at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:43)
>       at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe
>   (Subject.js:89)
>       at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:29)

recipe-detail.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.id = +params['id'];
          this.recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipe(this.id);
        }
      );
  }
```

recipe.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {
  recipesChanged = new Subject<Recipe[]>();

  private url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

  private recipes: Recipe[];

  constructor(private slService: ShoppingListService, private http: Http) {}

  getRecipes() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  getRecipe(index: number) {
    return this.recipes[index];
  }
```

recipe-detail.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes">
    <h1 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.id }}</h1>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.name }}</h4>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.username }}</h4>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.email }}</h4>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ recipe.phone }}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @dream88 - I'm currently using Angular 7

Comment: And when do you call `getRecipes()` ?

Comment: Maybe not relate to your issue, but you should consider changing `Http` in `constructor(private slService: ShoppingListService, private http: Http) {}` to `HttpClient`: [read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

Comment: @selemmn - getting the data from jsonplaceholder but the error is in getRecipe method

Comment: @dream88 - have that constructor already. The error is in getRecipe method

Comment: @imajgavz I do not see where you call that function in your code above, you just declare it in your service, and then ? when this function is executed ?

Comment: @selemmn -  I used/called getRecipe in the component.

Comment: @imajgavz You called `getRecipe()` , I mean `getRecipes()` , there is a difference !

Comment: @selemmn - please disregard `getRecipes()` method. I'm encountering the issue on `getRecipe()` method which I declared in the component.ts above

Comment: no , in fact your problem comes from `getRecipes()`, since there where you should fill your `recipes`, and then proceed with the `getRecipe()` to return the object BASED on the empty array , that's whith returns `of undefined`, since your array is empty, and that's logic tho !

Comment: @selemmn -  Oh, I got it know. But how I will return the object to the empty array not resulting to undefined?

Comment: @imajgavz, because then your array is not empty, you'll have `recipes[0]`, `recipes[1]` ...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the recipes are null/undefined. So when you call getRecipe(0) this error comes up.. Try changing your method to something like this:

```
getRecipe(index: number) {
    if (!!this.recipes && this.recipes.length > index) {
       return this.recipes[index];
    } else {
       return 0; //Whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Error not displaying now but the data from jsonplaceholder not diplaying also

Answer (score 0):

`private recipes: Recipe[]`  is not initialized here. You must have check for `undefined` and `length` before accessing the element.

### Component

```
getRecipe(index: number) {
    if(this.recipes && this.recipes.length > index){
        return this.recipes[index];
    }else{
       return null;
    }
```

}

### RecipeService

```
@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {
  recipesChanged = new Subject<Recipe[]>();

  private url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/";

  private recipes: Recipe[];

  constructor(private slService: ShoppingListService, private http: Http) {
      this.getRecipes().subscribe(recipes=>this.recipes); //<-- you may call from somewhere else.
  }

  getRecipes() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }

  getRecipe(index: number) {
    return this.recipes[index];
  }
```

Comment: Error not displaying now but the data from jsonplaceholder not diplaying also

Comment: You should call `getRecipes` to get the recipes. I updated the answer. I called in constructor but you can initialize from other places too.

Answer (score 0):

In the component you pass in the id to the getRecipe() method of the service. But, you cannot be sure it exists which is why it is occurring. Also, where, in the service, does 'recipes' come from? You initialize it, but never assign it any value (especially as an array). I.e., you aren't calling getRecipes() at all.

So alter the service:

```
getRecipe(index: number) {
  return this.recipes[index] ? this.recipes[index] : null;
}
```

So now in your component this.recipe may equal 'null' but you won't get the error.