# angular 5 extract data from response

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

product-service.ts

```
provinsi():Observable<any> {
return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/provinsi').pipe(
map(this.extractData),
catchError(this.handleError));
}
public extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res;
return body || {};
}
```

restaurant.ts

```
provinsi() {
    this.pservice.provinsi()
        .subscribe(data => this.provinsis = data.results);
}
```

json

```
{"results":[{"province_id":"1","province":"Bali"},{"province_id":"2","province":"Bangka Belitung"} . . .
```

i need a way to extract my json to angular / ionic view , when i run my apps, still appear "runtime error"

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Do you mean JSON.Parse?

Comment: cannot pass into my view  - "runtime error"

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in `extractData`. You are returning a `Response` object so when you are using that you do not have the expected json. To solve this, get the json from the `Response` object using the `.json()` method:

```
 public extractData(res) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
 }
```

**Tip**: You can use a ES6 feature called destructuring when you access to a json property. e.g:

```
provinsi() {
    this.pservice.provinsi()
        .subscribe(({ results }) => this.provinsis = results);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to work with TypeScript classes, you need to import the `Response` class from `@angular/http`:

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

This class was deprecated. You can check the new usage in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4)

Comment: It is with parenthesis like `({ results }) =>`. This is a new ES6 feature called destructuring @AzizalYunanP

Comment: i've added import Http response , but still not working