# Angular seeing JSON as string and not object

Tags: json, angular, http

I am returning JSON from restful API

```
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://myAPI.net/api/TAFGetAllUsers/0')
  }
```

which is called in

```
users: object;
ngOnInit() {
    this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data
      console.log(this.users)
    })
  }
```

However, the console output is plain JSON text:

```
{   "Users": [
    {
      "UserId": "4B4D1C12-48FD-4C1D-91F7-03C18FEC8B86",
      "UserTypeId": 1,
      "Name": "Tommy",
      "EmailAddress": "email1@pie.co.uk",
      "DateCreated": "2019-03-22T09:28:04.553"
    },
    {
      "UserId": "232D7596-3DD8-40A1-B4B0-15A54A6A102A",
      "UserTypeId": 3,
      "Name": "Alexis",
      "CompanyName": "Sony",
      "EmailAddress": "ds3@sony.com",
      "DateCreated": "2019-03-20T11:53:53.360"
    },
    {
      "UserId": "1BB22695-1B4D-4E42-8A95-16D1E9B1EF59",
      "UserTypeId": 3,
      "Name": "Richard",
      "CompanyName": "Microsoft",
      "EmailAddress": "email2@bob.com",
      "DateCreated": "2019-03-20T13:57:22.183"
    }   ] }
```

It isn't seen as an object. If I do

```
data[0]
```

it just returns '['

Also if I do

```
data.Users
```

it returns "undefined".

I'm unable to directly do

```
 JSON.parse(data)
```

as it sees data as an object, giving an error of "Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

I've tried converting the data object to string then parse to JSON

```
 this.rawUsers = JSON.stringify(data);

 this.users = JSON.parse(this.rawUsers);
```

But this outputs the same as the default data value, acting like a string.

Comment: replace `this.users = data` by `this.users = data.Users`

Comment: what version of Angular do you use (Http or HttpClient for request)?

Comment: @BahadorRaghibizadeh Doing data.Users is always undefined as it doesn't seem to recognize data as a JSON object.

Comment: @Vadi using Angular CLI version 8.3.5

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers? And specifically `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unable to directly do `JSON.parse(data)` as it sees data as an object, giving an error of "Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

That can be fixed with type assertion:

```
JSON.parse(data as string)
```

and if that *still* throws an error,

```
JSON.parse(data as any as string)
```

(Not the most elegant workaround, but should work).

Comment: You're welcome. But I'd still look at the response headers, something must be causing Angular interpreting the response as a text string, and I suspect it's the headers.

Comment: I tried adding "{headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}}" to the http.get() though this results in the angular app in browser only displaying "Cannot GET /" and a 404 error in console

Answer (score 2):

You have the following structure of object:

```
{ "Users": [ ] }
```

So you should write like that to get an array of your users:

```
this.data.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data.Users) {
      this.users = data.Users;
      console.log(this.users);
  } else {
      console.log(data);
  }

})
```

UPDATE:

This line of code throws an error `this.rawUsers = JSON.stringify(data);`
because **your data is already json object**. Because

> JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed

See [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865)

Comment: Doing data.Users is always undefined as it doesn't seem to recognize data as a JSON object.

Comment: yeah, stringify was a throwing stuff at the wall atempt to get it working, your suggested solution still displays the data as a string and doing ".Users" is always seen as undefined

Comment: @Vereonix do you mean that your code always gets into `else` statement? `else {      console.log(data);  }`?

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
this.users = data.Users;
```

[**Stackbliz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5efysb)

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below:

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

Hope this will help you.