# Differences in Observables between Angular2 and Angular8

Tags: angular, observable, angular8

I had created some functions related to Observables in Angular2 for an app I was developing. But since then, I haven't use Angular. So, my working functions related to Observables have to be modified accordingly in order to become functional in Angular8 and I can't get rid of some error messages.

The **API** from the server returns an array of objects from the database:

```
router.get('/getEntries, (req, res, next) => {
   db.get().collection('data').find().toArray((err, data) => { res.json(data); });
});
```

The problem probably is in the **entry.service.ts** file:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map}        from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Entry}      from '../Classes/entry';

@Injectable()
export class EntryService {

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getEntries(): Observable<Entry[]> {
      return this.http.get('http://192.168.1.3:3000/api/getEntries').pipe(map(res => res.json() as Entry[]));
   }

} //end of Service
```

The **app.component.ts** is the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Entry}             from '../Classes/entry';
import {EntryService}      from '../Services/entry.service';

@Component({
   selector    : 'app-root',
   templateUrl : './app.component.html',
   styleUrls   : ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   entries: Entry[];

   constructor(private entryService: EntryService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.entryService.getEntries().subscribe(data => {this.entries=data;}, err => {console.log(err);});
   }

} //end of Component
```

The old working **entry.service.ts** file in Angular2 is the following:

```
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
import { Http }                 from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Entry }                from '../Classes/entry';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EntryService {

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   getEntries(): Observable<Entry[]> {
      return this.http.get('http://192.168.1.3:3000/api/getEntries').map(res => res.json() as Entry[]);
   }

} //end of Service
```

Now, in Angular 8, *.json()* function doesn't exist anymore.
How can I adjust my code in Angular 8 in order to work??

Generally speaking, is my method of handling http requests a good practice or could it be implemented with a better manner? I don't know Angular in-depth so this is why i'm asking.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: it does it by default, you can remove the `.map`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HttpClient`class from `HttpClientModule` if you're using Angular 4.3.x and above:

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

```
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule
 ],
 ...

 class MyService() {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {...}
```

It's an upgraded version of http from @angular/http module with the following improvements:

- Interceptors allow middleware logic to be inserted into the pipeline
- Immutable request/response objects
- Progress events for both request upload and response download
- JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed
- Typed, synchronous response body access, including support for JSON body types

You can read about how it works [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf).

Also pay attention that old http was injected using `Http` class token instead of the new `HttpClient`

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpModule
 ],
 ...

 class MyService() {
    constructor(http: Http) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient.get()` applies `res.json()` automatically and returns Observable>. You no longer need to call this function yourself.

See [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-httpmodule-and-httpclientmodule/45129865#45129865)

Don't need to use this method:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: there's no benefit to having the last line `.map(res => res);` should just remove it completely, its redundant.

Comment: yea agree @c_ogoo