# Angular 4 GET request with multiple Headers throws 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to do a POST request with headers to get a response. Below is the Angular code I am using for request.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Token':'$1$IGinaeBw$Z2kYO175lQ5t2H5HWCdOV1',
        'User-Id':'1'
    });

 this.http.get('http://localhost/simple-codeigniter-rest-api-master/index.php/book/', {headers:headers} )
    .map(user => {
       if (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
        console.log(user);
        return user;
    });
```

Below is the issue I am getting in the console.

[image: 1]

Its working fine in PSOTMAN though. Since angular version is upgrading constantly. I am not sure what's the issue.

Note: JQuery AJAX call is working fine.

POSTMAN screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It's a cors issue, No need to afraid. What kind of technolgy you are using for backend?

Comment: No it isn't. Angular has a built in CORS notification. If it were a cors issue, angular would say so.

Comment: CORS issues are more verbose about it

Comment: Can you please check your network tab result?

Comment: It might be a mistake of wrong input data

Comment: Try to do following with headers:  const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
And try to debug the endpoint on your backend too

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request

Comment: If cookies are used, POSTMAN will add it automatically, and for your angular get(), you should do as fallows: const headers = new Headers(); headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain'); let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true});

Comment: I thought RequestIOptions is deprecated? I seen in angular.io.

Comment: RequestOptions is used on Angular4, I have a working app that use it

Answer (score -1):

```js
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

 constructor(private http: Http) {
       
 }
 
     const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        headers.append('User-Id', `$1$IGinaeBw$Z2kYO175lQ5t2H5HWCdOV1`);
        headers.append('Token', `1`);


       const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
       this.http.get(
           "http://localhost:3000/contacts",
           options
       ).subscribe();
```

There is a possible solution for you:

Check input of headers and Content type (application/json,..)

Comment: How to check. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: Share me the screen of working postman, just give me the image

Comment: const headers = new Headers(); headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: You need to know exactly what you send and what you receive, I struggled with same thing one time, and I can assure you with post() you will suffer more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739745/angular-4-doesnt-include-headers-to-http-request

Comment: @praveenkumars I added postman screenshot in question. Do you get any idea?

Comment: @johnie I send u a link which consist the right ans for u, I modified the ans for you

Comment: I am getting this error when using this requestOtions : 
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.

Comment: this was a working example of mine. And did u add this "import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
" in top

Comment: Now am getting the error in options in this line  

return this.http.get('http://localhost/simple-codeigniter-rest-api-master/index.php/book/', options )       as

Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.

Comment: Depending on Backend you use. Example in my case .NET core,  i needed to AllowAnyHeader()

Comment: @praveenkumars Still seeing the same issue in options. in the line
this.http.get(
         "http://localhost/simple-codeigniter-rest-api-master/index.php/book/",
         options
     )

Answer (score -1):

Just try this one,

Add import in top,

`import {Http, Headers,Response, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';`

Add in constructor -> `private http: Http`

```js
 var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    headers.append('user_id', '3');
    headers.append('Token', '2313131313');
    this.http.get('your api url', {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
          let result = response.json();
        }
      );
```

This will work for you think so

Comment: If this not work for you, then you have to solve it in your php CORS handler

Comment: When I am adding Http in construct am getting an error as :
taticInjectorError(AppModule)[AuthService -> Http]:

If it's a CORS error How its working in JQuery then.

Comment: I think Http is deprecated. You are providing me with an old solution.

Comment: @johnie try don't send 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' in the header