# HTTP GET request with HttpAuth Params

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I need to make a HTTP request in my angular solution.
I have created a service with a HTTP client.

However, I can't seem to add the right headers.

Here is what the working request looks like in python :

```
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

How can I 'translate' this into the right request for my example ? :

```
public getFile() {
  return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/user', {headers :myGetHeaders});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `httpOptions object` which is passed from httpclient as shown below. It is essentially a map in which you can define various request header.

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

Now you can do

```
return this.http.get('https://api.github.com/user', httpOptions );
```

You can refer to [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739873/6407858) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer was helpful for my code, but I still can't get my request to work properly. I need to pass my 'username' and 'password' as params somewhere.

Comment: @Zako do you mean as query params or path params?

Comment: if it is query param you can use ?username='user'&password='pass'. For path params as the name suggest you can directly pass them in the path. But for security reasons you should avoid sending username and password as path params

Comment: Yeah I think what's wrong is the way I'm trying to do it. I've read that it might be easier to pass a token instead of credentials. Gonna try this way : 


new httpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'zfkgn4432qyxnrsmdl3xdbrsf2lnsrmba4deu6vyri3mwlhbpyju', 'Content-Type':  'application/json'});



Thank you!