# What is the equivalent of php getallheaders() function in Angular 4/5?

Tags: php, angular, http-headers

What is the equivalent of php getallheaders() function in Angular 4/5 ?

I need to get request headers but i can't find this in Angular.

I can get only response headers with Angular.

Comment: I am looking for Request header when application start localhost:4200

Answer (score 0):

**Request:**

Look here: [How to correctly set Http Request Header in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133705/how-to-correctly-set-http-request-header-in-angular-2)

*Interceptor:*

```
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(request.headers); // log request headers
        let headers = request.headers // here you can get your headers
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')); 

        const cloneReq = request.clone({ headers });

        return next.handle(cloneReq);
    }
}
```

**Response:**

Look here:
[Angular 4.3.3 HttpClient : How get value from the header of a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505619/angular-4-3-3-httpclient-how-get-value-from-the-header-of-a-response)

```
http
  .get<MyJsonData>('/data.json', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers); // log response headers
  });
```