# HttpClient leading to error

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 and want to start using `HttpClient`. However I get JSON parsing error and after alot of searching I have not been able to fix it yet.

Old method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { AppConfig } from '../config/app.config';
import { AuthenticateService } from '../security/shared/authenticate.service';
import { IFlower } from './flower.model';

addFlower(Flower: IFlower): Observable<any> {
    this._auth.checkToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers, this._auth.token);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(this.apiUrl + 'flower/insert', JSON.stringify(Flower),
        this.options).map((res: Response) => <any>res).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Converting to HttpClient

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { AppConfig } from '../config/app.config';
import { AuthenticateService } from '../security/shared/authenticate.service';
import { IFlower } from './flower.model';

    addFlower(Flower: IFlower): Observable<any> {
        this._auth.checkToken();
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._auth.token,
                'Content-Type':  'application/json'
            })
        };

        return this._http.post<any[]>(this.apiUrl + 'flower/insert', JSON.stringify(Flower), httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

On converting to HttpClient I get the following error message

[image: Console error]

Backend Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("insert")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddFlower(Flower flower)
{
    try
    {
        _flowerervice.AddFlower(flower, token));
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden"));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw ExceptionMessageUtility.HttpResponse(Request, exception);
    }
}
```

I have been looking around SO and other sources. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133705/how-to-correctly-set-http-request-header-in-angular-2/46172188#46172188) SO post explains HttpClient but this still does not resolve my error. Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent breaking-change in Angular's `HttpClient` means that deserializing a JSON body with `HTTP 200 OK` responses with empty content now trigger this "unexpected end of data at ... of the JSON data" error because it should be using `HTTP 204 No Content`. See here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20879

There are 3 possible fixes:

1. Change your web-service so it returns HTTP 204 with an empty body.
2. Change your web-service so it returns HTTP 200 with a non-empty body.
3. Change your client code so it will return the empty response as a string instead of attempting to deserialize it as JSON (set `{ responseType: "text" }`).

Comment: Dai, thank you for the response. I will try to post a response after testing all 3 scenarios.