# Typescript what is the type of the object : "{ [name: string]: string}"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I started working with angular HttpHeaders but could not understand one of the parameters of its constructor which is **[name: string]: string** , here is the constructor from the docs :

```
constructor(headers?: string | { **[name: string]: string** | string[]; })
```

could anyone explain the type of that object or what it does refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

So the full type declaration you shared `headers?: string | { [name: string]: string | string[]; }` is saying that `headers` can be 1 of 2 types: a string, or an object with a specific shape.

For example:

- **string**: `"some value"`
- **object** (with a `string` value): `{ some: "value" }`
- **object** (with a `string[]` value): `{ some: ["value", "foo"] }`

The index signature `{ [name: string]: string | string[]; }` is specifically saying that any key `name` that is a string can be used and it's value can be either a `string` or an array of strings (`string[]`). The `name` in `[name: string]` actually has no significance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way of declaring an Object, or you could say a dictionary, a key/value pair. Where you do not need to define the properties (different from an interface), you just say that the key will be of type `string` and the value of type (in this case) `string | string[]`.

So, when you set your headers as `{'Accept': 'application/json'}`, for example, you are creating a pair where key is `'Accept'`, of type string, and this key's value is `'application/json'`, also of type string.

That way of declaring a type let's you have, of course, multiple dynamic properties, so you could end up with:

```
const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}`,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It means you can just pass in headers as one string, or object list of string header definitions.
If you're looking on the best way to set your headers check this:

```
 let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append(
    'Accept',
     'text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0. 8'  
    );
```

or this answer here:

[How to correctly set Http Request Header in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133705/how-to-correctly-set-http-request-header-in-angular-2)