# Request header for http get request using angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http-headers, httprequest

In my application, I'm using angular 8 client to get data from my spring boot server, here is the get requesr from the server:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Flowers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public HttpEntity<FlowersList> getFlowersFromFlowers(@RequestHeader String realityId, 
 @RequestParam("mName") String mName)
```

And my relecent client code:

```
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
params: new HttpParams().set('realityId', '0')
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getFileList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`,this.httpOptions);
}
```

I keep on getting the following error from the server:

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'realityId' for 
method parameter of type String]
```

I was trying to follow this [stuck overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475523/how-to-pass-url-arguments-query-string-to-a-http-request-on-angular) and [this tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-pass-url-parameters-query-strings/)
but didn't get any luck.
I want to pass in my request header the value '0'(string) for the server's 'realityId' field.
Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this one for quite awhile

edit:
been trying to do it like this:

```
 httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'realityId': '0' })
};
```

still nothing..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly set Http Request Header in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133705/how-to-correctly-set-http-request-header-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Rick thank you for your answer, I forgot to mention, I'm using angular 8