# Custom service in extended Http not getting injected

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-http

I want to extend the `Http` provider to intercept all requests that deliver a 403 status to handle an automatic logout.
My custom `InterceptingHttp` should be declared as `Http` provider, so I don't need to care about a "special" http provider.

I have to following:

**My custom Http provider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Response, Http, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../services/authentication.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptingHttpService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    var self = this;
    return super.request(url, options).catch((res: Response) => {
        if (res.status === 403) {
        console.log('intercepted');
        self.authenticationService.logout();
        }
        return Observable.throw(res);
    });
    }
}
```

**The declaration as regular Http provider in NgModule**

```
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ToastyModule.forRoot(),
        HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
        routing,
        Ng2BootstrapModule,
    PaginationModule
    ],

    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavHeaderComponent,
        FooterCopyrightComponent,
        InventoryRootComponent,
        InventoryTreeComponent,
        InventoryDetailComponent,
        SetModelComponent,
        MetadataListComponent,
        MetadataDetailComponent,
        ScriptGeneratorComponent,
        SetDetailComponent,
        SetVersionComponent,
        SetContainerTreeComponent,
        SetContainerDetailComponent,
        FilterByPropertyPipe,
        OrderContainersByLeafPipe,
        ResolveStateId,
        ConfirmComponent,
        FocusDirective
    ],
    providers: [
    SetService,
        SetTypeService,
        SetContainerService,
        StateService,
        NotificationService,
        MetadataService,
        MetadataTypeService,
        EntityService,
        SetContainerMetadataService,
    AuthenticationService,
    InterceptingHttpService,
        ConfirmService,
        SiteVersionService,
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, authenticationService: AuthenticationService) => {
        return new InterceptingHttpService(backend, defaultOptions, authenticationService);
        },
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthenticationService]
    },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

It gets loaded and it does intercept all 403 responses. The only odd thing is, that the `authenticationService` is undefined.

I guess I'm probably do a mistake in my providers declaration. I tried to add `AuthenticationService` to the `deps` array, which only resulted into an Circular dependency error.

Where is my mistake? How can I use my `AuthenticationService` in my extended Http provider?

Comment: There is no need for `self` if you use `() =>`.

Comment: Have you checked in the constructor like `constructor(...) { super(...); console.log(authenticationService); }` whether a value was passed in?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's correct. This was a left over. Thanks

Comment: As expected it's `undefined`

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? There was an issue with DI and extended classes a while ago.

Comment: I'm currently on 2.1.0

Comment: That's >2 months old. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210-incremental-metamorphosis-2016-10-12 I think you should update.

Comment: I just update to 2.3.1 but I still got the same issue.

Comment: _I tried to add AuthenticationService to the deps array, which only resulted into an Circular dependency error"_. That's your problem. Redesign your classes so you don't have this. There is never a need for a circular dependency if your classes are design correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `AuthenticationService` to `deps`

```ts
deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthenticationService]
```

When `Http` is injected to `AuthenticationService` this will cause a circular dependency that DI can't resolve.

See [DI with cyclic dependency with custom HTTP and ConfigService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233) for an approach how to work around circular dependency.

Comment: I've been trying this, but also with the new version of angular it ends up with `Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Http: in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule `

Comment: If just updated my question with the complete ngModule declaration

Comment: `AuthenticationService` probably does inject `Http`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233

Comment: I tried it with the solution from the additional link you posted and it now works as expected. Maybe you can add the link to your answer too with a comment about circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - done. Glad to hear you could make it work :)