# Ionic2/Angular2 Cyclical Dependencies

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 rc4.

I have an issue where I am getting an error due to a cyclical dependency.

```
  +-------------------------------------+
  |    LoginEmailPage    RegisterPage   |
  |           ↓           ↓↑            |
  |           UtilityService            |
  +-------------------------------------+
```

I have a class `LoginEmailPage` that makes use of `UtilityService`.

e.g. from `LoginEmailPage`:

```
this.utilityService.login(nav)
```

In `UtilityService`:

```
public login(nav: NavController): void {
    nav.popTo(RegisterPage);
}
```

`RegisterPage` also makes use of the `utilityService`, so I get an compile time error:

> ```
> metadata_resolver.js:623Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginEmailPage: (FirebaseAuth, MenuController,
> ```
>
> NavController, NavParams, FormBuilder, ViewController,
>   AlertController, PersonService, ?, Events, LoadingController).
>           at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:39298:19)

Where the `?` is `UtilityService`.

**Question**

How can I have a service (`UtilityService`) navigate to a page (`RegisterPage`) that already references the service(`UtilityService`)?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Due to advise below:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233), I have tried using an `Injector`:

**utilityService.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";

    private registerPage: RegisterPage = null;
    constructor(injector: Injector,...
        setTimeout(() => this.registerPage = injector.get(RegisterPage));

    public login(nav: NavController): void {
        nav.popTo(this.registerPage);
    }
```

But I still get the same error as above.

Second, I look at [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#forwardref) and [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/faq/), which suggests to make use of `forwardRef`. My problem is that my service is an `@Injectable` and not a `@Component`. So the [examples](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-access-page-instance-inside-custom-component-with-native-ionic2-directives/44074/3) I see, does something like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: `<div>
               <icon></icon>
               <input type="button" />
             </div>`,
  directives: [forwardRef(() => MyIcon)] // MyIcon has not been defined yet
})                                       // forwardRef resolves as MyIcon when MyIcon is needed
```

**Question**

How can I get this to work with a service that is not a component, but rather an injectable?

**UPDATE**

Fore more information, I am adding the constructors of each file.

**loginemail.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'loginemail.html'
})

export class LoginEmailPage {
...
    constructor(public auth: FirebaseAuth, menu: MenuController, public nav: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public builder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController, alertCtrl: AlertController, personService: PersonService, utilityService: UtilityService, events: Events, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
```

**register.ts**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'register.html'
})

export class RegisterPage {
...
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public builder: FormBuilder, personService: PersonService,
        public viewCtrl: ViewController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, utilityService: UtilityService, events: Events,
        public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public auth: FirebaseAuth) {
```

**utilityService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UtilityService {
...
    constructor(injector: Injector, alertCtrl: AlertController, menu: MenuController, popoverController: PopoverController, storage: Storage) {
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to advise below, I try [this](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html).

**utilityService.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject, forwardRef } from "@angular/core";
import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';

@Injectable()
export class UtilityService {
...

public registerPage: RegisterPage = null;

     constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => RegisterPage)) registerPage, ...
        this.registerPage = registerPage;
          ...
          nav.popTo(this.registerPage, { personModel });
```

But I still the original compile error. I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

In the `RegisterPage`, I use `forwardRef`:

```
constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => UtilityService)) utilityService
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: No provider for RegisterPage!

So I add `RegisterPage` to the `providers` in `app.modula.ts`, but then I get:

> ```
> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Provider parse errors:
> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! RegisterPage: in NgModule AppModule
> Error: Provider parse errors:
> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! RegisterPage: in NgModule AppModule
> ```

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860202/di-with-cyclic-dependency-with-custom-http-and-configservice/40860233#40860233

Comment: you could use forward reference https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#forwardref

Comment: Thanks for you assistance, but I have tried an `Injector` and a `forwardRef` as you guys suggest, but cannot get either to work. I have UPDATED my explanation above to include more detail on this. If you can suggest anything, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `forwardRef` should not be necessary if each class is in its own file. Only if you need to reference classes further down in the same file `forwardRef` is required.

Comment: I guess we need to see the constructors with parameters list of all involved service and component classes.

Comment: Yes, each class is in its own file. Will add the constructors...

Comment: I don't get from your graphic at the top what exactly the cycle looks like. Perhaps you need to inject the `Injector` somewhere else. `forwardRef` won't help you here. The problem is that Angular can't inject a class before the constructor is called, and it can't pass constructor parameters after the class was instantiated. `forwardRef` is only to break cycles in TypeScript code, not in constructor parameter dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `forwardRef` in the constructor of your component
eg:

```
export class LoginEmailPage {
constructor(...
     @Inject(forwardRef(() => UtilityService))utilityService, events: Events,
        public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public auth: FirebaseAuth) {
```

Check [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html)

Also `RegisterPage` and `LoginEmailPage` are components not providers (injectable). It should not be set in constructor of UtilityService.

Comment: Hi Suraj, thanks for your input. I have tried what you suggest, but I must be doing something incorrectly. Please can you have a look at my UPDATE in the description above.

Comment: or try in login page since there you are getting error. I do not know your dependency graph to know wer the cycle is

Comment: I can make reference to the UtilityService from the `RegisterPage` and `LoginEmailPage`, so I need to do this in the `UtilityPage`. I will update the description above to show my dependencies more clearly.

Comment: Are you importing Register page in loginemailpage?

Comment: I don't thin that `forwardRef` will work, because I think the `import` of the cyclic dependency is causing the error. I did look at using `require`, but couldn't get that to work either. (e.g. `this.pages['RegisterPage'] = require('../register/register').RegisterPage;`)

Comment: Yes, I am importing the `RegisterPage` in the `LoginEmailPage`. But not visa versa.

Comment: then you need to to use forwardRef utilityservice in loginemailpage

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.

Comment: I try add the forwardRef to the `LoginEmailPage` and `RegisterPage` for the `UtilityService`, but I get: `Error: No provider for RegisterPage!`. See UPDATE above.

Comment: The page is a component not a provider.. remove from constructor..You can use in the service like you use in any component (eg. pushing in navcontroller)

Comment: I'm confused, you say I must remove it from the constructor, but then I don't have a forwardRef and I'm back to my original code.

Comment: forward ref the service(provider) in component. component cant be injected in providers constructor

Comment: That's my whole question from the beginning. I have a cyclic dependency because my service needs to popTo the component. So I either need to reference the component from the service, or a total redesign.

Comment: In the loginemailpage you refer RegisterPage by only importing and not by injecting in constructor.. thats my point. you do the same way in provider

Comment: import and use in provider and dont inject

Comment: I see, thanks for your patience. From the `UtilityService`, when I `import` the `RegisterPage`, I get no errors, but as soon as I `nav.popTo(RegisterPage)`, I get original compilation error.

Comment: Yes, I still get the original error posted.  `Can't resolve all parameters for LoginEmailPage: (?, FirebaseAuth...`. It's as if it doesn't like the `LoginEmailPage` using a service that makes reference to a page it already imports.

Comment: then am not sure.. forwardref on provider has worked for me in a similar situation

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will continue to try with forwardRef. I think you have pointed me in the right direction.